# How override audit field @CreatedDate in spring 4?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-form

How override audit field @CreatedDate in spring 4 ?
Example code in entity

```
    @Column(name = "begin_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date beginDate;
```

I try to set field value through a web the form, but all the same there is current datetime

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to store a datetime from a web form shouldn't you add this field to the entity separately?

Alternatively, remove the `@CreatedDate` annotation and post the date time from the form.

Also, Might I suggest using `JodaTime` for datetime. It's an excellent library and works very well with JPA/Hibernate.

[JodaTime Link](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

[JodaTime with Hibernate Annotations](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html)